React Native: DraggableFlatList Flickering During Drag on Physical Device
I'm using the react-native-draggable-flatlist library to implement a draggable list in my React Native app. While dragging an item, it briefly flickers back to its original position before snapping into the new position. On the snack provided by react-native-draggable-flatlist it seems to be working fine but when i clone it it doesnt. https://snack.expo.dev/@computerjazz/draggable-flatlist-examples So im thinking it might be an issue with my device?
Edit: Maybe its a newer Expo version breaking it?
